# Can someone help identify this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I know these questions come up all the time, but im really stuck -

Ive tried all variations of "Helvetica" as I thought it looked most similiar, in addition to all standard MS Word Fonts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows).

The font looks the most like "Frutiger" however, Frutiger does not have a two-storey/hour-glass lower case "g". Are there any other fonts I could look into?

Any help would be appreciated. Ive tried online font discovery programs with no luck.

[image: Font sample 1]
[image: Font sample 2]
[image: Font sample 3]

Answer (score 1):

According to [WhatTheFont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), it's Linotype News Gothic No. 2

Yours:

[image: yours]

Linotype

[image: lino]

In the future, check that site out.  You upload a sample image and it IDs the font for you.